# Around vs along vs over vs down, meaning "to a place"

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> I went **around** to the post office/my sister's house.
>
> I went **along** to the post office/my sister's house.
>
> I went **over** to the post office/my sister's house.
>
> I went **down** to the post office/my sister's house.

Any nuances about the distance, how I got to the place, etc?

Comment: Assuming that you went X to some place, [go around to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-around) 4. to visit a person or a place; [go along](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/go-along_1) to go to a place or event, usually without much planning; [go over to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-over) 3. to move or travel towards someone or something; [go down](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-down) 6. to travel towards the south (a. BrE: to travel to a place that is smaller or less important than where you are)

Comment: That's not the whole story, I might think. But I am sorry not to be able to provide any context. @Damkerng T

Comment: And what if the main verb is not "go", but "come", "walk", "move", etc? That's why I didn't mark "went" bold in my question.

Comment: If you asked that it would sound to me like, "What does X (e.g. *around*) mean when it is used with any of all possible verbs", and that would be too broad of a question. I don't like to say that we might need to learn the sense of each preposition being used in each specific case one case at a time, but it sadly seems to be so, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of prepositions can be *optionally* added after *to go [**to** some place]*...

> ***around*** (or more commonly, ***round***) - the former is often in contexts where the route is circuitous/indirect *("I went around to my sister's house on the other side of the lake")*. Note that when ***round*** is used, ***to*** is very often omitted *("On Fridays I go round my sister's for dinner")*.
>
> ***across*** - places more emphasis on the *terrain to be crossed*. Perhaps because your sister's house is on the other side of town (or the street). Perhaps because you used a boat to get *across the lake*.
>
> ***along*** - often implies "on foot", and/or a relatively short distance. May also imply an unplanned or trivial action, and/or a journey accompanied by or intending to meet up with other people.
>
> ***over*** - similar to ***across*** and ***along***.
>
> ***down*** (or ***up***) - often reflects either a *literal* height difference, or figurative *(e.g. - **up** = towards a major population centre).*
>
> ***out*** - often implies *leaving* the building you started from and/or going *outside*.
>
> ***by*** - implies your visit to the other location was brief, and/or was a diversion from your current route.

There are almost certainly other equally common alternatives that I can't think of offhand.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, yes.  They all imply the post office is a convenient distence from your starting point.

If the post office was far, you would say:

> I wen all the way to the post office.

"along" however does not belong with the rest.  "I went along" means you accompanied someone else to the post office, but it was not necessarily your destination.